# Does indexing a text in mysql improve searching text with LIKE '%search%'

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, innodb

I am using InnoDB engine in mysql **version:5.1.61-community-log**. The length of text to be searched is less than 100 characters. Does the performance of queries with **LIKE '%searchstring%'** improve with indexing the text ?

EDIT:
I am using this query for jquery auto-suggest component.
I am using 3rd party webhosting service . So upgrade is not an option for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, adding an index won't help your `LIKE '%foo%'` queries (much*). A `LIKE` condition can only use the index efficiently if you have a constant prefix, such as `LIKE 'foo%'`

You should consider a [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) instead. If you are on MySQL 5.5 or older only the MyISAM engine was supported. In MySQL 5.6 or newer InnoDB is also supported for full text searches.

If you are using an older version of MySQL, are unable to upgrade, and are unable to change the storage engine (because you need other features of InnoDB such as foreign key constraints), then you could consider creating a new MyISAM table which stores only the primary key and the text column. You can use this table to perform fast full text searches and join to the original table if you also need access to the other columns.

You could also consider using an external text search engine such as:

- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)

<sub>(*) If the index you add is a *covering index* for your query, you will get a small improvement by adding an index. Due to the smaller width of the index, a full scan of the index will be faster than a full scan of the entire table.</sub>

Comment: As given in reference full text can only be used with MyISAM. My rest of the tables use InnoDB engine. Will it be a good idea to use MyISAM in one table and InnoDB in rest? This table is  INNER JOINed  with rest of the tables a lot.

Comment: @Terminal: Full text searches can only be used with the MyISAM engine if you're using MySQL 5.5 or lower. In MySQL 5.6 InnoDB is also supported. What version of MySQL are you using? Is upgrading an option?

Comment: My current mysql version: 5.1.61-community-log .I am using a webhosting service, so  upgrade in not an option for me